# Windows store app - true/false slider

Tags: javascript, windows-8, slider, windows-store-apps

I tryed to find windows true/false slider element, but without any succes. I try to use `input range`, but this is not the same. I can use checkboxes for 0 - 1 value, but I realy need those slider's here.

They look's like this:
[image]

How can I create them in JavaScript application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That control is called a [ToggleSwitch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701411.aspx).  Create it in HTML like this:

```
<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch">
</div>
```

or in JavaScript like this:

```
var object = new WinJS.UI.ToggleSwitch();
```